# How to get symbols on the lines of a table

Tags: tables, symbols

I want to generate a table like this with latex. Can you help?
I can write a normal table as below, but have no idea how to create those symbols on the lines.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\toprule
      & Scenario 1 & Scenario 2 \\
\midrule
Val 1 & x     & y \\
\midrule
Val 2 & x     & Z \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image: Table with symbols on the lines]

Answer (score 15):

This is a solution using `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle,
      draw,
      text width=6em,
      align=center
    },
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    text depth=0.5ex,
    text height=2ex,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row 1/.style={
      minimum height=0.5cm,
    },
    column 1/.style={
      nodes={
        text width=3em
      }
    }
    },
  circ/.style={
    draw=green,
    circle,
    fill=white,
    thick,
    minimum width=0.8cm
  }
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (table) [ampersand replacement=\&, table]
  {
   \& Scenario 1 \& Scenario 2 \\
   Val 1 \& $\alpha + \beta^2$ \& $\gamma + \beta\delta^2$ \\
   Val 2 \& $\alpha + \beta^2$ \& $\alpha + \beta^2$ \\
  };

  \node[circ] (less) at ($(table-2-2)!0.5!(table-2-3)$){$<$};
  \node[circ] (equals) at ($(table-2-2)!0.5!(table-3-2)$){$=$};
  \node[circ] (question) at ($(table-3-2)!0.5!(table-3-3)$){$?$};
  \node[circ, rotate = -90] (greater) at ($(table-2-3)!0.5!(table-3-3)$){$>$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering if the cells can be of different sizes? column headers and row headers are of different size compared to value cells in the table.

Comment: @mucalinda Sure, how about now?

Answer (score 7):

A `pstricks` solution. Note you shouldn't use the rules from `booktabs` with vertical rules, as they do not intersect. I replaced them with `\Xhline`s from `makecell`, thereof thickness has to be specified:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\setcellgapes{9pt}\makegapedcells
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vline width 1pt}l|l|l!{\vline width 1pt}}
\Xhline{1pt}
      & Scenario 1 & Scenario 2 \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Val 1 & \Rnode{S1t}{$\alpha + \beta^2 $} & \Rnode{S2t}{~$\gamma + \beta\delta^2 $} \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Val 2 & \Rnode{S1b}{$\alpha + \beta^2 $ }& \Rnode{S2b}{~$\alpha + \beta^2 $} \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\psset{linecolor=YellowGreen, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=White,}
\nput[labelsep=1.5em]{0}{S1t}{\pscirclebox{$ < $}}
\nput[labelsep=1.25em]{0}{S1b}{\pscirclebox{?}}
\nput[labelsep=0.1ex]{105}{S1b}{\pscirclebox{$ = $}}
\nput[labelsep=0.05ex, rot=-90]{90}{S2b}{\pscirclebox{$ > $}}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an attempt to combine the advantages of the existing nice answers [by Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468135/121799) and [by caverac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468125/121799). What I like about Bernard's nice answer is that you can use the ordinary LaTeX tables with all their powerful methods to align things and so on. (Note, however, that I center the lower right entries as in your screen shot.) The IMHO big advantage of caverac's nice answer is that you are not restricted in your choice of your compiler, because it is based on Ti*k*Z, and that there are no hard-coded dimensions. (I am using `midway` instead of the `calc` syntax, not because I consider it "better" but just to show an alternative.) To this end I use the `tikzmark` library to arrive at something which might be called a Ti*k*Zy version of Bernard's proposal (which most of the code is borrowed from)

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\setcellgapes{9pt}\makegapedcells
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vline width 1pt}l|c|c!{\vline width 1pt}}
\Xhline{1pt}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Scenario 1} &\multicolumn{1}{l!{\vline width 1pt}}{Scenario 2} \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Val 1 & \tikzmarknode{S1t}{$\alpha + \beta^2 $} & \tikzmarknode{S2t}{$\gamma +
\beta\,\delta^2 $} \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Val 2 & \tikzmarknode{S1b}{$\alpha + \beta^2 $ }& \tikzmarknode{S2b}{$\alpha + \beta^2 $} \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember
picture,gc/.style={midway,circle,draw=green!60!black,thick,fill=white,inner
sep=2pt}]
\path (S1t.east) -- (S2t.west) node[gc] {$<$};
\path (S1b.east) -- (S2b.west) node[gc] {?};
\path (S1t.south) -- (S1b.north) node[gc] {$=$};
\path (S2t.south) -- (S2b.north) node[gc,rotate=90] {$<$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]